# add class to the header if current router

Tags: angular, typescript

i am learning Angluar 8 and all i need to do is if the /capabilities routers is active it will add a class name called 'white' to the header 
to allocate the active route i will use the capabilities (cap) components to allocate if the route is active 
and in cap component i will call a function from the AppServiceService this function in AppServiceService will call change the boolean variable to true to add the class the console.log statement works fine but it doesn't add the class :(

this is the header component

```
<header class="main_header" [ngClass]="{'active': isWhite}">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col_lg_3">
            <a routerLink=""><img src="https://redhornstaging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/logo.svg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col_lg_9">
            <ul class="navbar_list">
                <li><a routerLink="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="/capabilities">Capabilities</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="/works">Works</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav_item_btn" routerLink="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

this is the cap component

```
    export class CapComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router , private app:AppServiceService ) { }
  //check if the current route is capabilities it will call function from the service
  is_Active(){
    if(this.router.url == '/capabilities'){
      this.app.applyHeader();
      // console.log(this.router.url);
    }
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.is_Active();
  }

}
```

and this is the AppServiceService

export class AppServiceService {

```
constructor(public nav:NavbarComponent) { }
// nav = new NavbarComponent; 
 applyHeader(){
   this.nav.isWhite = true;
   console.log("Hello from service");
 }
```

}

the last component which have the problem however when i change the way to call the function from the same component it works well

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  isWhite : boolean = false ;

  constructor() { }
  makeItWhite(){
    this.isWhite = true ;
    if(this.isWhite){
      console.log('white !');
    }
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: Basically do you want to highlight active route ?

Comment: No i need to add class if this route is active

Comment: Why not do all this inside the header component?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are attempting to access and set a component's property from a singleton service. This is bad practice. From the outset, it may look like you are simply accessing a class' property from another class in typescript. But in Angular, singleton services serve a different purpose. Please see [here](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services). In short, singletons are used to provide common functionalities common properties between different component's controllers.
2. You could subscribe to `events` observable of `router` to check against the current route in `AppServiceService`. Try the following

AppServiceService

```js
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

export class AppServiceService {
  private isCapabilitiesSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public isCapabilities$ = this.isCapabilitiesSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this._router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(
      event => {
        if (event['urlAfterRedirects'] === 'capabilities') {
          this.isCapabilitiesSource.next(true);
        } else {
          this.isCapabilitiesSource.next(false);
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Header component

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _appService: AppServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Header component template

```
<header class="main_header" [ngClass]="{'active': (_appService.isCapabilities$ | async)}">
```